# Getting reference. Expected content

Tags: perl, yaml

I have this script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use YAML::Syck;

my $x = {'x' => [1,2,3],
     'y' => {'z' => 8},
     'q' => 'abc',
};

my $yaml = YAML::Syck::Load($x);
print "\n" . $yaml . "\n\n\n";

my $h = YAML::Syck::Dump($yaml);
print Dumper $h;
```

which outputs

```
HASH(0x7539cb0)


$VAR1 = '--- HASH(0x7539cb0)
';
```

I'd expected to see the structure of `$x` which content. What's wrong there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `Dump` to dump a Perl data structure into YAML and `Load` to do the opposite.
Try:

```
my $yaml = YAML::Syck::Dump($x);
print "\n" . $yaml . "\n\n\n";

my $h = YAML::Syck::Load($yaml);
print Dumper $h;
```

Answer (score 3):

You have Load() and Dump() reversed; Load takes YAML and produces a perl datastructure; Dump takes a perl datastructure and produces YAML.